# How to sort dropdown in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have try to order by dropdown using angularjs. but, sorting not working. Please help me. Please check this link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bschauhan/tu568yj0/3/)

**HTML:**
My Html code Here

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in charityList | orderBy:'value'" ng-model="reportSearch.charityId">
     <option value="">All Charity</option>
</select>
```

**JSON ARRAY:** My Json "Key=>Value" array for using dropdown list

```
 $scope.charityList = {
     "1": "softweb charity",
     "2": "charity 1",
     "3": "charity update",
     "4": "Engagement1 Name",
     "6": "United Way Enagagement",
     "7": "Indian Noble Charity"
 }
```

Please check this link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bschauhan/tu568yj0/3/)

Comment: you want to sort list by Key or Value ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an object not an array. And array is defined by chevrons.

```
charityList = [ 
     {"name": "softweb charity"}, 
     {"name": "charity 1"},
     {"name": "charity update"},
     {"name": "Engagement1 Name"},
     {"name": "United Way Enagagement"},
     {"name": "Indian Noble Charity"}
],
```

If you can make it look this way you can sort it with orderBy

```
ng-options="value.name for value in charityList | orderBy:'name'"
```

Comment: key is my requirement..I have not remove of key (1,2,3,4,6,7)

Comment: can you create plunker of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry,dude, OrderBy only working with arrays. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/d8Ldygv7/

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

controller:

```
$scope.sort = function(list) { //returns an array : ["charity 1","charity update","Engagement1 Name","Indian Noble Charity","softweb charity", "United Way Enagagement"]
  return $.map(list, function(el) { return el }).sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
  });
}
```

html :

```
<select ng-options="value as value for value in sort(charityList)" ng-model="reportSearch.charityId">
     <option value="">All Charity</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I checked your fiddle but the orderBy in your fiddle won't work because as per syntax parameters to orderBy should be a "property in an array of objects" whereas in your case charityList is a single "object" . Thats why in my answer I'm calling function sort() which returns a sorted array of values in <key,value> pair.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to transform you object into an array of objects or else orderBy will not work.

```
 angular.forEach($scope.charityList, function(value, key) {
        arr.push({key: key, value: value})

      })
```

[fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/dhLme0hj/)